# Node.js Fails to run windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js

Running node.js on Win7 simply executes then returns to the command prompt.  Has anyone seen this behavior?  Env path to node.exe is good.  Any suggestions to remedy?

node -v --> v0.8.19

[image]

Comment: It's so non-blocking it doesn't even wait for user input in interpret mode.

Comment: it's not true, just tried.

Comment: Works perfectly on every other Win7 device I've tried just this one.  Pulling hair out.  Is it conflicting with something else installed?

Comment: do you installed the correct node, I mean 64bit on win64 or 32bit on win32?

Comment: I've actually tried both.  I'm certain at this point that it is something local to my machine but just unsettling that I can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: Not sure it this matters but, have you tried running it on a simple cmd.exe instead of using PowerShell?